# Using regex in the heredocument redirect/append line, to target specific "sets" of directories

Tags: bash, scripting, regular-expression, io-redirection, here-document

I need a way to target all sub directories under `public_html` which ends with `.com` or other [TLDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) like `.biz` or `.co.il` I might list, in a [heredocument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document).

This my hereoducmnet inside an `pushd-popd` - `if-fi` statement nested inside a `for` loop:

```
for dir in "$HOME"/public_html/*/; do
    if pushd "$dir"; then
        cat <<-"EOF" >> "$HOME"/public_html/ALL_DOT_COM|ALL_DOT_BIZ/.htaccess

           Apache_directive_set_1

           Apache_directive_set_2

           popd
        EOF
    fi
done 2>myErrors.txt
```

Is there a way to combine regex to achieve that, directly inside the heredocument redirect/append line (where `ALL_DOT_COM|ALL_DOT_BIZ` is)?

Comment: @DopeGhoti question edited: The desired output is the first empty line, the apache_directive set_1, the second empty line, the apache_directive_set_2, and the third empty line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to append to `.htaccess` in all directories like `$HOME/public_html/foo.com/`, `$HOME/public_html/bar.biz/` etc.

Your `for` loop already manages processing all directories, the question is then just to adjust the glob to just match the required endings:

```
for dir in "$HOME"/public_html/*.{com,biz,co.il}/; do
    cat <<-"EOF" >> "$dir"/.htaccess
        Apache directives...
        ...
    EOF
done 2>myErrors.txt
```

There doesn't seem to be any need for the `cd`, since `dir` already contains the full path of the directory.

The above will of course only match the listed top-level domains. (I'm not sure if this is what you want, since you wrote "or other TLDs".) If you don't care which TLD there is on the directory name, just use `.../public_html/*/`, or `.../public_html/*.*/`, though that still assumes there's nothing else in there. (But then, listing *all* the TLDs is a bit awkward, and they might come up with more...)

Comment: Listing as you show is best, I actually preferred that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using `tee -a` to append to a number of files, and a brace expansion.

I also don't think that the loop is actually needed, as `tee` does the work of writing into multiple files at once.

```
cat <<-"EOF" | tee -a "$HOME"/public_html/*.{com,biz,co.il}/.htaccess
       Apache_directive_set_1
       Apache_directive_set_2
EOF
```

The string

```
"$HOME"/public_html/*.{com,biz,co.il}/.htaccess
```

will be expanded into

```
/home/something/public_html/*.com/.htaccess /home/something/public_html/*.biz/.htaccess /home/something/public_html/*.co.il/.htaccess
```

and then the globs will do their work matching against the appropriate subdirectories.

If there is a risk that a glob might not match anything, you should probably also set the `nullglob` shell option in `bash`:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

With this option set, a glob pattern that does not match any existing filename will be expanded to an empty string.

---

If the pattern `"$HOME"/public_html/*.{com,biz,co.il}/.htaccess` expands to a string that is far too long, you may have issues running `tee`.  In this case you *do* need the loop:

```
for dir in "$HOME"/public_html/*.{com,biz,co.il}/
do
    cat <<-"EOF" >>"$dir/.htaccess"
           Apache_directive_set_1
           Apache_directive_set_2
    EOF
done
```

There's still no need to `cd` into the directories though.